# Sharing contracts between WCF client and service

Tags: wcf, assemblies, client, sharing

It was my understanding that when a developer (a company) develops both client and service, it’s better to put data and service contracts into a separate assembly to be used by both client and service applications. It is to avoid code duplication while generating a proxy classes using e.g. svcutil.

Is this indeed the preferred approach and have you ever had a project that was an exception from this rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this all the time in our projects and i don't know what can be said against that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing contract assembly can lead to unwanted dependencies, since these contract classes such as datacontract\servicecontract can contain methods. These methods then can get called transparently in client\server code hence breaking the encapsulation of these contracts. Data\Service contracts are meant to be used only as an mechanism to share data.

Comment: Service contracts are usually just interfaces so there are only method declarations. As for data contracts, I meant them as pure DTOs, without any methods.
So I don't see any sign of breaking the encapsulation. Client and server apps seem to remain loosely coupled.

Comment: But nothing stops one from defining methods on these DTO and consuming these methods from client side.